# No handlers could be found for logger "scss" ( widgy )

Tags: django

i have tried to run the functionnality of widgy, but there are many graphical bug, in the admin module, Page, forms, callout etc..., nothing is display normally, as i can compare with the demo on the official site.

```
I have followed the entire quickstart. 

COMPRESS_ENABLED = True
COMPRESS_PRECOMPILERS = (
    # ...
    ('text/x-scss', 'django_pyscss.compressor.DjangoScssFilter'),
    # ...
)

Thanks for any help.

   No handlers could be found for logger "scss"
[15/Jan/2015 13:18:15] "GET /fr/admin/widgy_mezzanine/widgypage/1/ HTTP/1.1" 200 22283
[15/Jan/2015 13:18:16] "GET /fr/admin/jsi18n/ HTTP/1.1" 200 6395
[15/Jan/2015 13:18:16] "GET /static/CACHE/js/424ba88f8f6e.js HTTP/1.1" 200 46207
[15/Jan/2015 13:18:16] "GET /static/CACHE/css/05e35ee5ec67.css HTTP/1.1" 200 26931
[15/Jan/2015 13:18:16] "GET /static/widgy/js/widgy.js?1421324273.839 HTTP/1.1" 200 4833
[15/Jan/2015 13:18:16] "GET /static/widgy/js/jquery-private.js?1421324273.839  HTTP/1.1" 200 128
[15/Jan/2015 13:18:16] "GET /static/widgy/js/lib/csrf.js?1421324273.839 HTTP/1.1" 200 1143
[15/Jan/2015 13:18:16] "GET /static/widgy/js/widgy.backbone.js?1421324273.839 HTTP/1.1" 200 6595
[15/Jan/2015 13:18:16] "GET /static/widgy/js/shelves/shelves.js?1421324273.839 HTTP/1.1" 200 5163
[15/Jan/2015 13:18:16] "GET /static/widgy/js/require/text.js?1421324273.839 HTTP/1.1" 200 12340
[15/Jan/2015 13:18:16] "GET /static/widgy/js/nodes/nodes.js?1421324273.839 HTTP/1.1" 200 15860
[15/Jan/2015 13:18:16] "GET /static/widgy/js/geometry.js?1421324273.839 HTTP/1.1" 200 776
[15/Jan/2015 13:18:16] "GET /static/widgy/js/nodes/base.js?1421324273.839 HTTP/1.1" 200 6082
[15/Jan/2015 13:18:16] "GET /static/widgy/js/lib/mustache.js?1421324273.839 HTTP/1.1" 200 15447
[15/Jan/2015 13:18:16] "GET /static/widgy/js/lib/underscore.js?1421324273.839 HTTP/1.1" 200 41662
[15/Jan/2015 13:18:16] "GET /static/widgy/js/app.html?1421324273.839 HTTP/1.1" 200 27
[15/Jan/2015 13:18:16] "GET /static/widgy/js/nodes/preview.html?1421324273.839 HTTP/1.1" 200 83
[15/Jan/2015 13:18:16] "GET /static/widgy/js/shelves/shelf.html?1421324273.839 HTTP/1.1" 200 98
[15/Jan/2015 13:18:16] "GET /static/widgy/js/modal/modal.js?1421324273.839 HTTP/1.1" 200 1825
[15/Jan/2015 13:18:16] "GET /static/widgy/js/nodes/drop_target.html?1421324273.839 HTTP/1.1" 200 24
[15/Jan/2015 13:18:16] "GET /static/widgy/js/nodes/models.js?1421324273.839 HTTP/1.1" 200 7242
[15/Jan/2015 13:18:16] "GET /static/widgy/js/nodes/popped_out.html?1421324273.839 HTTP/1.1" 200 39
[15/Jan/2015 13:18:16] "GET /static/widgy/js/modal/modal.html?1421324273.839 HTTP/1.1" 200 227
[15/Jan/2015 13:18:16] "GET /static/widgy/js/lib/q.js?1421324273.839 HTTP/1.1" 200 43423
[15/Jan/2015 13:18:16] "GET /static/widgy/js/lib/fixto.js?1421324273.839 HTTP/1.1" 200 13848
[15/Jan/2015 13:18:16] "GET /static/widgy/js/lib/backbone.js?1421324273.839 HTTP/1.1" 200 59594
[15/Jan/2015 13:18:17] "GET /static/widgy/js/lib/jquery.js?1421324273.839 HTTP/1.1" 200 252881
[15/Jan/2015 13:18:17] "GET /static/widgy/js/components/widget/component.js?1421324273.839 HTTP/1.1" 200 71
[15/Jan/2015 13:18:17] "GET /admin/widgy/node/1/available-children-recursive/ HTTP/1.1" 200 8077
[15/Jan/2015 13:18:17] "GET /static/widgy/js/widgy.contents.js?1421324273.839 HTTP/1.1" 200 5536
[15/Jan/2015 13:18:17] "GET /static/widgy/js/form.js?1421324273.839 HTTP/1.1" 200 2335
[15/Jan/2015 13:18:17] "GET /static/widgy/js/templates.js?1421324273.839 HTTP/1.1" 200 790
[15/Jan/2015 13:18:18] "GET /static/widgy/font/fontawesome-webfont.woff?a4d31bad427a HTTP/1.1" 200 41752

Thanks for your quick answer. 

Now my logs files looks like : 

File to import not found or unreadable: 'widgy_layout.scss' (<string u'@import "widgy_layout.scss";\n@import "widgy_theme_'...>:0)
File to import not found or unreadable: 'widgy_theme_default.scss' (<string u'@import "widgy_layout.scss";\n@import "widgy_theme_'...>:0)
File to import not found or unreadable: '/widgy/css/widgy_common' (<string u'@import "/widgy/css/widgy_common";\n\n// Layout\n.wid'...>:0)
Mixin not found: box-sizing:1 (<string u'@import "/widgy/css/widgy_common";\n\n// Layout\n.wid'...>:6)
Mixin not found: clearfix:0 (<string u'@import "/widgy/css/widgy_common";\n\n// Layout\n.wid'...>:6)
Mixin not found: cursor:1 (<string u'@import "/widgy/css/widgy_common";\n\n// Layout\n.wid'...>:31)
Mixin not found: cursor:2 (<string u'@import "/widgy/css/widgy_common";\n\n// Layout\n.wid'...>:34)
Mixin not found: cursor:2 (<string u'@import "/widgy/css/widgy_common";\n\n// Layout\n.wid'...>:37)
File to import not found or unreadable: 'tabbed-theme.admin.scss' (<string u'@import "/widgy/css/widgy_common";\n\n// Layout\n.wid'...>:0)
File to import not found or unreadable: '/widgy/css/widgy_common.scss' (<string u'@import "/widgy/css/widgy_common.scss";\n\n$table-ce'...>:0)
File to import not found or unreadable: 'table-theme.admin.scss' (<string u'@import "/widgy/css/widgy_common.scss";\n\n$table-ce'...>:0)
Can't find any matching rules to extend: %horizontalChildren
File to import not found or unreadable: '/widgy/css/widgy_common.scss' (<string u'@import "/widgy/css/widgy_common.scss";\n\nli.node,\n'...>:0)
Mixin not found: node-icon-sprite:2 (<string u'@import "/widgy/css/widgy_common.scss";\n\nli.node,\n'...>:3)
Mixin not found: node-icon-sprite:2 (<string u'@import "/widgy/css/widgy_common.scss";\n\nli.node,\n'...>:3)
Mixin not found: node-icon-sprite:2 (<string u'@import "/widgy/css/widgy_common.scss";\n\nli.node,\n'...>:3)
Mixin not found: node-icon-sprite:2 (<string u'@import "/widgy/css/widgy_common.scss";\n\nli.node,\n'...>:3)
Mixin not found: node-icon-sprite:2 (<string u'@import "/widgy/css/widgy_common.scss";\n\nli.node,\n'...>:3)
Mixin not found: node-icon-sprite:2 (<string u'@import "/widgy/css/widgy_common.scss";\n\nli.node,\n'...>:3)
Mixin not found: node-icon-sprite:2 (<string u'@import "/widgy/css/widgy_common.scss";\n\nli.node,\n'...>:3)
Mixin not found: node-icon-sprite:2 (<string u'@import "/widgy/css/widgy_common.scss";\n\nli.node,\n'...>:3)
Mixin not found: node-icon-sprite:2 (<string u'@import "/widgy/css/widgy_common.scss";\n\nli.node,\n'...>:3)
Mixin not found: node-icon-sprite:2 (<string u'@import "/widgy/css/widgy_common.scss";\n\nli.node,\n'...>:3)
Mixin not found: node-icon-sprite:2 (<string u'@import "/widgy/css/widgy_common.scss";\n\nli.node,\n'...>:3)
Mixin not found: node-icon-sprite:2 (<string u'@import "/widgy/css/widgy_common.scss";\n\nli.node,\n'...>:3)
Mixin not found: node-icon-sprite:2 (<string u'@import "/widgy/css/widgy_common.scss";\n\nli.node,\n'...>:3)
Mixin not found: node-icon-sprite:2 (<string u'@import "/widgy/css/widgy_common.scss";\n\nli.node,\n'...>:3)
Mixin not found: node-icon-sprite:2 (<string u'@import "/widgy/css/widgy_common.scss";\n\nli.node,\n'...>:3)
File to import not found or unreadable: '/widgy/css/widgy_common.scss' (<string u'@import "/widgy/css/widgy_common.scss";\n\n.widgy .n'...>:0)
Mixin not found: html:0 (<string u'@import "/widgy/css/widgy_common.scss";\n\n.widgy .n'...>:4)
File to import not found or unreadable: '/widgy/css/widgy_common.scss' (<string u'@import "/widgy/css/widgy_common.scss";\n\nli.node,\n'...>:0)
Mixin not found: node-icon-sprite:2 (<string u'@import "/widgy/css/widgy_common.scss";\n\nli.node,\n'...>:3)
Mixin not found: node-icon-sprite:2 (<string u'@import "/widgy/css/widgy_common.scss";\n\nli.node,\n'...>:3)
Mixin not found: node-icon-sprite:2 (<string u'@import "/widgy/css/widgy_common.scss";\n\nli.node,\n'...>:3)
Mixin not found: node-icon-sprite:2 (<string u'@import "/widgy/css/widgy_common.scss";\n\nli.node,\n'...>:3)
Mixin not found: node-icon-sprite:2 (<string u'@import "/widgy/css/widgy_common.scss";\n\nli.node,\n'...>:3)
Mixin not found: node-icon-sprite:2 (<string u'@import "/widgy/css/widgy_common.scss";\n\nli.node,\n'...>:3)
Mixin not found: node-icon-sprite:2 (<string u'@import "/widgy/css/widgy_common.scss";\n\nli.node,\n'...>:3)
Mixin not found: node-icon-sprite:2 (<string u'@import "/widgy/css/widgy_common.scss";\n\nli.node,\n'...>:3)
Mixin not found: node-icon-sprite:2 (<string u'@import "/widgy/css/widgy_common.scss";\n\nli.node,\n'...>:3)
Mixin not found: node-icon-sprite:2 (<string u'@import "/widgy/css/widgy_common.scss";\n\nli.node,\n'...>:3)
Mixin not found: node-icon-sprite:2 (<string u'@import "/widgy/css/widgy_common.scss";\n\nli.node,\n'...>:3)
Mixin not found: node-icon-sprite:2 (<string u'@import "/widgy/css/widgy_common
```

Answer (score 1):

The app scss is trying to log some message (maybe a warning) but you haven't configured any handler for it.

Just configure one, using the handler you prefer.

```py
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'file': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': '/path/to/django/debug.log',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'scss': {
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    },
}
```